# Python 3 - Remove characters from results

Tags: python, printing, strip

I need help to figure out how to strip off the 1st x amount of characters from a list result:

My code is;

```
id = [i.get_attribute('id') for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"name")]]')]
links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[contains(., "href")]')]
for n,u in zip(id,links):
    print(n,u,sep=',')
```

This displays correct, something like this;

```
name-12345678, url1

name-23311212, url2

name-23311212, url2
```

...and so on.

What I need help with is how to remove name. At this point I just want the id numbers, so results will be:

```
12345678, url1

23311212, url2

23311212, url2
```

All help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `print(n.split('-')[1], u, sep=',')` should do it. But there might be a better xpath solution. Wait and see.

Comment: Nice one, that worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
id = [i.get_attribute('id').replace("name-", "") for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"name")]]')]
```

Comment: Thanks, this also works, thanks for the suggestion, Always good to know multiple ways of achieving the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.strip()` method, for you code:

```
id = [i.get_attribute('id') for i in 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[@id[starts-with(.,"name")]]')]
links = [i.get_attribute('href') for i in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a[contains(., "href")]')]
for n,u in zip(id,links):
    print(n.strip("name-"),u,sep=',')
```

And if you like, you would also use regex.